# Loading global environment variables in an Ansible task

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ansible

I have several global environment variables set in `/etc/environment` on my target machine that I need to present when running some Ansible tasks. E.g.

```
MY_VAR=Some global variable
```

The value of these global variables are **not** known to Ansible so I can't use the `environment` functionality.

Example task:

```
- shell: echo MY_VAR is $MY_VAR
  register: my_var

- debug: msg={{ my_var.stdout }}
```

The output I get is `MY_VAR is` where I would like it to be `MY_VAR is Some global variable`. I understand that this is happening because non-interactive Bash shells (which Ansible uses) don't load the environment from `/etc/environment`, but is there a way to execute my command in the context of that environment?

**Note:** I don't actually want to retrieve the value of the environment variable (as shown above), I just want it to be present in the context that I execute the `shell` task in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote environment variables are available via facts using the the `ansible_env` variable.

This prints out all variables of the user Ansible logs into a remote host with:

```
- debug: var=ansible_env
```

If global environment variables not available to the Ansible user, they can be sourced in a task before running your command:

`- shell: . /etc/environment && commandhere`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The problem is that when the command is executed, the global variables in `/etc/environment` aren't part of the environment.

Comment: Ah i see, how about sourcing it before running your command: 
  `- shell: . /etc/environment && commandhere`